# Making a Table of Contents/ or Index in Google Blogspot

Tags: indexing, blogspot, tableofcontents

I have a personal blog on Google Blogspot - www.purple-webs.blogspot.com

I was wondering if there is a way that I can have a table of contents or an index sort of thing for my blog?

Any help or new ideas are appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate, how should it look like? your question is much to vage.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. For example my blog has different short stories on it. (For reference check purple-webs.blogspot.com) Here if the first page or the front page could be an index page, or table of contents page? In which the visitor can click on the story by title and that would take him to the particular post.